# Show that $\mathbb{V}[X \mid Y] = \mathbb{V}{[X]}-Cov(X,Y)\mathbb{V}(Y)^{-1}Cov(X,Y)^T$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Consider two normally distributed RVs $X,Y$. Show that
> $$\mathbb{V}[X \mid Y] = \mathbb{V}{[X]}-Cov(X,Y)\mathbb{V}(Y)^{-1}Cov(X,Y)^T.$$
> Hint: Use that $$\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] = \mathbb{E}[X]+B(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y]),$$
>
> where $B = Cov(X,Y)\mathbb{V}(Y)^{-1}$.

I tried to use the definition of conditional variance:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{V}[X \mid Y] &= \mathbb{E}[X^2 \mid Y] - \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]^2\\
& = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]^2\\
\\
&\text{When I plug in the expression from the hint I get:}\\
\\
&= \mathbb{E}[X^2] - (\mathbb{E}[X]+B(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y]))^2\\
&= \mathbb{V}[X^2] -2\mathbb{E}[X]B(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])-B^2(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])^2
\end{align}

I do not see how to continue from here, for when I plug in the definition of $B$ I only get some messy terms. Could you please help me?

Comment: this doesn't look right.. are you sure that the hint is written correctly? I think it should be $E[X|Y] = E[X]+B$

Comment: You were right, I had misread $B$. I edited my question.

Comment: Your approach will not be fruitful. The reason is that the stated property is (afaik) unique to the normal distribution. Hence you need to use the fact that the rv are normally distributed: 1. compute the conditional density of $X|Y$, that is, $f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$, 2. use the fact that $\frac{\exp(A)}{\exp(B)} = \exp(A-B)$, 3. use the block inversion formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Applications_to_probability_theory_and_statistics), 4. simplify, 5. the desired result follows.